# group_by, look up value for group, return value and original data.frame? (efficiently, using dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to `group_by`, locate the first appearance of a row that meets a criterion, and create a new column with a value based that selected row from each group.

#### Example

This is easy to demonstrate with an example. A new column should be generated by

1. grouping by transaction_id
2. looking for the first appearance of icecream_bool ( = 1) (note that the second transaction has two rows that meet this criteria, so the first should be taken)
3. creating a new column using the value located in the 'item' column

We start with this data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(
  transaction_id=as.integer(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)),
  item=as.character(c("crisps", "magnum", "gum",
                      "jerky", "cheese", "snickers", "ben&jerry", "magnum",
                      "halo", "crisps", "mars")),
  icecream_bool=as.integer(c(0,1,0,
                             0,0,0,1,1,
                             1,0,0)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

#    transaction_id      item icecream_bool
# 1               1    crisps             0
# 2               1    magnum             1
# 3               1       gum             0
# 4               2     jerky             0
# 5               2    cheese             0
# 6               2  snickers             0
# 7               2 ben&jerry             1
# 8               2    magnum             1
# 9               3      halo             1
# 10              3    crisps             0
# 11              3      mars             0
```

#### Desired output

Generate ice_cream column like so

```
   transaction_id      item icecream_bool ice_cream
1               1    crisps             0    magnum
2               1    magnum             1    magnum
3               1       gum             0    magnum
4               2     jerky             0 ben&jerry
5               2    cheese             0 ben&jerry
6               2  snickers             0 ben&jerry
7               2 ben&jerry             1 ben&jerry
8               2    magnum             1 ben&jerry
9               3      halo             1      halo
10              3    crisps             0      halo
11              3      mars             0      halo
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way if you only have 1's and 0's in `icecream_bool` is by using `which.max`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(transaction_id) %>%
  mutate(ice_cream = item[which.max(icecream_bool)])


#   transaction_id item      icecream_bool ice-cream
#            <int> <chr>             <int> <chr>    
# 1              1 crisps                0 magnum   
# 2              1 magnum                1 magnum   
# 3              1 gum                   0 magnum   
# 4              2 jerky                 0 ben&jerry
# 5              2 cheese                0 ben&jerry
# 6              2 snickers              0 ben&jerry
# 7              2 ben&jerry             1 ben&jerry
# 8              2 magnum                1 ben&jerry
# 9              3 halo                  1 halo     
#10              3 crisps                0 halo     
#11              3 mars                  0 halo
```

This can also be written in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ice_cream := item[which.max(icecream_bool)], transaction_id]
```

---

If there are values which are greater than 1 and we need to compare with 1 we can use `match`

```
df %>%
  group_by(transaction_id) %>%
  mutate(ice_cream = item[match(1,icecream_bool)])
```

Comment: Thanks! I am surprised that `which.max` doesn't stumble on the group with >1 max value (i.e. the second transaction in the example)

Comment: `which.max` by default returns the index of *first* maximum in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

One way using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(transaction_id, icecream_bool) %>%
  mutate(mr = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(transaction_id) %>%
  mutate(ice_cream=item[mr==1 & icecream_bool==1]) %>%
  select(-mr)
```

---

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   transaction_id [3]
   transaction_id item      icecream_bool ice_cream
            <int> <chr>             <int> <chr>    
 1              1 crisps                0 magnum   
 2              1 magnum                1 magnum   
 3              1 gum                   0 magnum   
 4              2 jerky                 0 ben&jerry
 5              2 cheese                0 ben&jerry
 6              2 snickers              0 ben&jerry
 7              2 ben&jerry             1 ben&jerry
 8              2 magnum                1 ben&jerry
 9              3 halo                  1 halo     
10              3 crisps                0 halo     
11              3 mars                  0 halo
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured out a similar way just before you posted. I'll time them both as the actual use case has a *lot* of rows (was going to take 91 hours in a loop!)

Comment: In that case data.table may be a better option.

Comment: don't they (dplyr and data.table) both use c++ under the hood. Or does data.table do something extra?

Comment: I know data.table does. But dplyr? Not sure. I can't keep up with the monthly changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(transaction_id) %>%
  mutate(icecream = first(item[icecream_bool == 1]))

# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   transaction_id [3]
   transaction_id item      icecream_bool ice      
            <int> <chr>             <int> <chr>    
 1              1 crisps                0 magnum   
 2              1 magnum                1 magnum   
 3              1 gum                   0 magnum   
 4              2 jerky                 0 ben&jerry
 5              2 cheese                0 ben&jerry
 6              2 snickers              0 ben&jerry
 7              2 ben&jerry             1 ben&jerry
 8              2 magnum                1 ben&jerry
 9              3 halo                  1 halo     
10              3 crisps                0 halo     
11              3 mars                  0 halo
```

Comment: *very* elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's efficient, but I found a way

```
df <- data.frame(
  transaction_id=as.integer(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3)),
  item=as.character(c("crisps", "magnum", "gum",
                      "jerky", "cheese", "snickers", "ben&jerry", "magnum",
                      "halo", "crisps", "mars")),
  icecream_bool=as.integer(c(0,1,0,
                             0,0,0,1,1,
                             1,0,0)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df %>% 
  group_by(transaction_id) %>% 
  filter(icecream_bool == 1) %>% 
  distinct(transaction_id, icecream_bool, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  select(-icecream_bool) %>% 
  rename(icecream=item) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by=c("transaction_id"="transaction_id"))


   transaction_id      item icecream_bool  icecream
1               1    crisps             0    magnum
2               1    magnum             1    magnum
3               1       gum             0    magnum
4               2     jerky             0 ben&jerry
5               2    cheese             0 ben&jerry
6               2  snickers             0 ben&jerry
7               2 ben&jerry             1 ben&jerry
8               2    magnum             1 ben&jerry
9               3      halo             1      halo
10              3    crisps             0      halo
11              3      mars             0      halo
```